# How to get Scriptblock to add an element to a form?

Tags: powershell

I have a script that launches a form and allows the user to make drop down selections.

The selections are then placed into an array.

I then need to validate 5 values of an array in a while loop and if all values are present a submit button will display.

The While loop is running in scriptblock however as this is essentially a separate code i cannot get it to add the submit button to the original form?

here is my code..

```
$BuildTech = "x:\Scripts\PowerShell\BuildTech.txt"
$Acrobat = "x:\Scripts\PowerShell\Acrobat.txt"
$Partition = "x:\Scripts\Powershell\Drives.txt"
$MSOffver = "x:\Scripts\Powershell\OfficeVer.txt"
$DepCode = "x:\Scripts\Powershell\DepCodes.txt"

$CompName = $Null

[array]$BuildTechDropArray = Get-Content $BuildTech
[array]$AcroDropArray = Get-Content $Acrobat
[array]$PartitionDropArray = Get-Content $Partition
[array]$MSOffVerDropArray = Get-Content $MSOffver
[array]$DepCodeDropArray = Get-Content $DepCode

[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing")
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")

[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles();

$Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form

$Radio1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton
$Radio2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton
$Radio3 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton
$Radio4 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton
$Radio5 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton
$Radio6 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton

$Radio1.Checked = $True

Function Get-OptimalSize()
{
    Param ([int64]$sizeInBytes)
    switch ($sizeInBytes)
    {
        { $sizeInBytes -ge 1TB } { "{0:n$sigDigits}" -f ($sizeInBytes/1TB) + " TB"; break }
        { $sizeInBytes -ge 1GB } { "{0:n$sigDigits}" -f ($sizeInBytes/1GB) + " GB"; break }
        { $sizeInBytes -ge 1MB } { "{0:n$sigDigits}" -f ($sizeInBytes/1MB) + " MB"; break }
        { $sizeInBytes -ge 1KB } { "{0:n$sigDigits}" -f ($sizeInBytes/1KB) + " KB"; break }
        Default { "{0:n$sigDigits}" -f $sizeInBytes + " Bytes" }
    }
}

$diskdrive = gwmi win32_diskdrive
$a =
foreach ($drive in $diskdrive)
{

    $InterFaceType = "$($Drive.InterfaceType)"
    If (!($InterFaceType -eq "USB"))
    {
        $Size = "$($drive.size)"
        $DriveModel = "`nDrive: $($drive.deviceid.substring(4))  Model: $($drive.model)"
        $Size = Get-OptimalSize $Size
        $DriveModel + "     " + $Size
        [Array]$a = $a + $Result
    }
}

$a = $a | Sort-Object

$Drive1 = $a[0] 
$Drive2 = $a[1]
$Drive3 = $a[2]
$Drive4 = $a[3]
$Drive5 = $a[4]
$Drive6 = $a[5]

If (-not ($Drive1 -eq $null)) { $Drive1 = $Drive1.trim() }
If (-not ($Drive2 -eq $null)) { $Drive2 = $Drive2.trim() }
If (-not ($Drive3 -eq $null)) { $Drive3 = $Drive3.trim() }
If (-not ($Drive3 -eq $null)) { $Drive4 = $Drive4.trim() }
If (-not ($Drive3 -eq $null)) { $Drive5 = $Drive5.trim() }
If (-not ($Drive3 -eq $null)) { $Drive6 = $Drive6.trim() }

If($a[0]){
    $DiskID1 = $a[0].SubString(21,1)
    $Radio1.BackColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::’Transparent’
    $System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
    $System_Drawing_Size.Width = 500
    $System_Drawing_Size.Height = 15    
    $Radio1.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
    $Radio1.TabIndex = 8
    $Radio1.Text = $Drive1
    $System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
    $System_Drawing_Point.X = 15
    $System_Drawing_Point.Y = 255
    $Radio1.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
    $Radio1.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
    $Radio1.Name = "Radio1"
    $Form.Controls.Add($Radio1)

}
If($a[1]){
    $DiskID2 = $a[1].SubString(21,1)
    $Radio2.BackColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::’Transparent’
    $System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
    $System_Drawing_Size.Width = 500
    $System_Drawing_Size.Height = 15
    $Radio2.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
    $Radio2.TabIndex = 9
    $Radio2.Text = $Drive2
    $System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
    $System_Drawing_Point.X = 15
    $System_Drawing_Point.Y = 275
    $Radio2.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
    $Radio2.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
    $Radio2.Name = "Radio2"
    $Form.Controls.Add($Radio2)
}
If($a[2]){
    $DiskID3 = $a[2].SubString(21,1)
    $Radio3.BackColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::’Transparent’
    $System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
    $System_Drawing_Size.Width = 500
    $System_Drawing_Size.Height = 15
    $Radio3.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
    $Radio3.TabIndex = 10
    $Radio3.Text = $Drive3
    $System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
    $System_Drawing_Point.X = 15
    $System_Drawing_Point.Y = 295
    $Radio3.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
    $Radio3.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
    $Radio3.Name = "Radio3"
    $Form.Controls.Add($Radio3)
}
If($a[3]){
    $DiskID4 = $a[3].SubString(21,1)
    $Radio4.BackColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::’Transparent’
    $System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
    $System_Drawing_Size.Width = 500
    $System_Drawing_Size.Height = 15
    $Radio4.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
    $Radio4.TabIndex = 11
    $Radio4.Text = $Drive4
    $System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
    $System_Drawing_Point.X = 15
    $System_Drawing_Point.Y = 315
    $Radio4.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
    $Radio4.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
    $Radio4.Name = "Radio4"
    $Form.Controls.Add($Radio4)
}
If($a[4]){  
    $DiskID5 = $a[4].SubString(21,1)
    $Radio5.BackColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::’Transparent’
    $System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
    $System_Drawing_Size.Width = 500
    $System_Drawing_Size.Height = 15
    $Radio5.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
    $Radio5.TabIndex = 12
    $Radio5.Text = $Drive5
    $System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
    $System_Drawing_Point.X = 15
    $System_Drawing_Point.Y = 335
    $Radio5.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
    $Radio5.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
    $Radio5.Name = "Radio5"
    $Form.Controls.Add($Radio5)
}
If($a[5]){
    $DiskID6 = $a[5].SubString(21,1)
    $Radio6.BackColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::’Transparent’
    $System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
    $System_Drawing_Size.Width = 500
    $System_Drawing_Size.Height = 15
    $Radio6.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
    $Radio6.TabIndex = 13
    $Radio6.Text = $Drive6
    $System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
    $System_Drawing_Point.X = 15
    $System_Drawing_Point.Y = 355
    $Radio6.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
    $Radio6.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
    $Radio6.Name = "Radio6"
    $Form.Controls.Add($Radio6)
}

    $Radio7 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton
    $Radio7.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(8,8)
    $Radio7.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(140,27)
    $Radio7.BackColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::’Transparent’
    $Radio7.Checked = $True
    $Radio7.Text = "WINDOWS 7"
    $Radio7.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
    $Radio7.Name = "Radio7"
    #$Radio7.TabIndex = 6
    #$groupbox1.Controls.Add($Radio7)

    $Radio8 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton
    $Radio8.BackColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::’Transparent’
    $Radio8.ForeColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::'Red'
    $Radio8.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(8,28)
    $Radio8.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(170,27)

    #$Radio8.TabIndex = 10
    $Radio8.Text = "WINDOWS 7 UPGRADE"

    $Radio8.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
$Radio8.Name = "Radio8"
#$Radio8.TabIndex = 7
    #$groupbox1.Controls.Add($Radio8)


$InitialFormWindowState = $Form.WindowState
$Form.add_Load($OnLoadForm_StateCorrection)

$LANDESK = [system.drawing.image]::FromFile("x:\Scripts\Powershell\logo-lg.gif")
$PS = [system.drawing.image]::FromFile("x:\Scripts\Powershell\PS2.png")
$PictureBox = New-Object Windows.Forms.PictureBox
$PictureBox.Image = $LANDESK
$PictureBox.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(12, 372)
$PictureBox.Width = $LANDESK.Size.Width
$PictureBox.Height = $LANDESK.Size.Height
$Form.Controls.Add($PictureBox)

$PictureBox2 = New-Object Windows.Forms.PictureBox
$PictureBox2.Image = $PS
$PictureBox2.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(588, 365)
$Form.Controls.Add($PictureBox2)

$Form.BackColor = 'White'
$Form.width = 698
$Form.height = 465

$Form.Text = "PowerShell Provisioning Tool                                                                                                                                 Gary Stewart 2014"
$Form.MinimizeBox = $False
$Form.MaximizeBox = $False
$Form.ControlBox = $False
$Form.topmost = $true

$MainLabel = new-object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$MainLabel.BackColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::’Transparent’
$MainLabel.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(10,5)
$MainLabel.size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(500,20)
$MainLabel.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font(“Tahoma Bold”, 14.25, 0, 3, 0)
$MainLabel.ForeColor = 'DimGray'
$MainLabel.Text = "PLEASE CUSTOMISE YOUR WINDOWS INSTALL"
$Form.Controls.Add($MainLabel)

$MainLabelWarning = new-object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$MainLabelWarning.BackColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::’Transparent’
$MainLabelWarning.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(10,352)
$MainLabelWarning.size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(450,20)
$MainLabelWarning.ForeColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::'Red'
$MainLabelWarning.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font(“Tahoma”,9.25, 0,3,0)
$MainLabelWarning.Text = "PLEASE ENSURE ALL OPTIONS ARE SELECTED BEFORE CLICKING SUBMIT"
$Form.Controls.Add($MainLabelWarning)

$BuildTechDrop = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
$BuildTechDrop.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(110,45)
$BuildTechDrop.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(198,21)
$BuildTechDrop.DropDownStyle = [System.Windows.Forms.ComboBoxStyle]::DropDownList;
$BuildTechDrop.tabIndex = 0
$Form.Controls.Add($BuildTechDrop)

$BuildTechDropLabel = new-object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$BuildTechDropLabel.BackColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::’Transparent’
$BuildTechDropLabel.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(12,47)
$BuildTechDropLabel.size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(90,20)
$BuildTechDropLabel.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font(“Tahoma Bold”,9.75, 0,3,0)
$BuildTechDropLabel.Text = "Build Tech"
$Form.Controls.Add($BuildTechDropLabel)

$AcroDrop = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
$AcroDrop.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(110,75)
$AcroDrop.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(198,21)
$AcroDrop.DropDownStyle = [System.Windows.Forms.ComboBoxStyle]::DropDownList;
$AcroDrop.tabIndex = 1
$Form.Controls.Add($AcroDrop)

$AcroDropLabel = new-object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$AcroDropLabel.BackColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::’Transparent’
$AcroDropLabel.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(12,75)
$AcroDropLabel.size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(95,20)
$AcroDropLabel.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font(“Tahoma Bold”,9.75, 0,3,0)
$AcroDropLabel.Text = "Adobe Acrobat"
$Form.Controls.Add($AcroDropLabel)

$PartitionDrop = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
$PartitionDrop.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(495,45)
$PartitionDrop.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(166,21)
$PartitionDrop.DropDownStyle = [System.Windows.Forms.ComboBoxStyle]::DropDownList;
$PartitionDrop.tabIndex = 2
$Form.Controls.Add($PartitionDrop)

$PartitionDropLabel = new-object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$PartitionDropLabel.BackColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::’Transparent’
$PartitionDropLabel.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(375,47)
$PartitionDropLabel.size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(90,20)
$PartitionDropLabel.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font(“Tahoma Bold”,9.75, 0,3,0)
$PartitionDropLabel.Text = "Partitioning"
$Form.Controls.Add($PartitionDropLabel)

$MSOffVerDrop = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
$MSOffVerDrop.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(495,75)
$MSOffVerDrop.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(166,21)
$MSOffVerDrop.DropDownStyle = [System.Windows.Forms.ComboBoxStyle]::DropDownList;
$MSOffVerDrop.tabIndex = 3
$Form.Controls.Add($MSOffVerDrop)

$MSOffVerDropLabel = new-object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$MSOffVerDropLabel.BackColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::’Transparent’
$MSOffVerDropLabel.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(375,75)
$MSOffVerDropLabel.size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(120,20)
$MSOffVerDropLabel.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font(“Tahoma Bold”,9.75, 0,3,0)
$MSOffVerDropLabel.Text = "MS Office Version"
$Form.Controls.Add($MSOffVerDropLabel)

$DepCodeDrop = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
$DepCodeDrop.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(110,105)
$DepCodeDrop.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(551,21)
$DepCodeDrop.DropDownStyle = [System.Windows.Forms.ComboBoxStyle]::DropDownList;
$DepCodeDrop.tabIndex = 4
$Form.Controls.Add($DepCodeDrop)

$DepCodeDropLabel = new-object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$DepCodeDropLabel.BackColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::’Transparent’
$DepCodeDropLabel.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(12,107)
$DepCodeDropLabel.size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(80,20)
$DepCodeDropLabel.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font(“Tahoma Bold”,9.75, 0,3,0)
$DepCodeDropLabel.Text = "Dep Code"
$Form.Controls.Add($DepCodeDropLabel)

$BarcodeInputLabel = new-object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$BarcodeInputLabel.BackColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::’Transparent’
$BarcodeInputLabel.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(12,135)
$BarcodeInputLabel.size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(95,21)
$BarcodeInputLabel.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font(“Tahoma Bold”,9.75, 0,3,0)
$BarcodeInputLabel.Text = "Insert Barcode"
$Form.Controls.Add($BarcodeInputLabel)

$BarcodeInput = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox 
$BarcodeInput.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(110,135) 
$BarcodeInput.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(198,21) 
$BarcodeInput.tabIndex = 5
$Form.Controls.Add($BarcodeInput)

$UpgradeOSCheck = new-object System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
$UpgradeOSCheck.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(15,160)
$UpgradeOSCheck.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(286, 24)
$UpgradeOSCheck.Text = "     WINDOWS 7 UPGRADE"
$UpgradeOSCheck.tabIndex = 6
$Form.Controls.Add($UpgradeOSCheck)

$App1Box = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
$App1Box.BackColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::’Transparent’
$App1Box.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(15,180)
$App1Box.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(250,24)
$App1Box.Text = "     INSTALL CISCO ANYCONNECT CLIENT"
$App1Box.TabIndex = 7
$Form.Controls.Add($App1Box)

$App2Box = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
$App2Box.BackColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::’Transparent’
$App2Box.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(15,200)
$App2Box.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(250,24)
$App2Box.Text = "     INSTALL AVAMAR CLIENT"
$App2Box.TabIndex = 7
$Form.Controls.Add($App2Box)

$FormatLabel = new-object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$FormatLabel.BackColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::’Transparent’
$FormatLabel.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(12,230)
$FormatLabel.size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(340,20)
$FormatLabel.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font(“Tahoma Bold”, 10.75, 0, 3, 0)
$FormatLabel.ForeColor = 'DimGray'
$FormatLabel.Text = "PLEASE SELECT DISK TO INSTALL OS ONTO"
$Form.Controls.Add($FormatLabel)

$WarningLabel = new-object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$WarningLabel.BackColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::’Transparent’
$WarningLabel.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(10,410)
$WarningLabel.size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(450,10)
$WarningLabel.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font(“Tahoma Bold”, 7, 0, 3, 0)
$WarningLabel.ForeColor = 'SteelBlue'
$WarningLabel.Text = "This tool is provided as is. It is not affiliated with LANDESK in any way. Thank you! "
$Form.Controls.Add($WarningLabel)


ForEach ($Item in $DepCodeDropArray) {
    $DepCodeDrop.Items.Add($Item)
}

ForEach ($Item in $MSOffVerDropArray) {
    $MSOffVerDrop.Items.Add($Item)
}

ForEach ($Item in $PartitionDropArray) {
    $PartitionDrop.Items.Add($Item)
}
ForEach ($Item in $AcroDropArray) {
    $AcroDrop.Items.Add($Item)
}
ForEach ($Item in $BuildTechDropArray) {
    $BuildTechDrop.Items.Add($Item)
}

$button = New-Object Windows.Forms.Button
$button.text = "SUBMIT"
$button.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(12, 423)
$button.size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(245, 37)
$button.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font(“Tahoma Bold”, 12.75, 0, 3, 0)
$button.BackColor = 'SteelBlue'
$button.ForeColor = "White"
$button.tabIndex = 14



    $DepCodeDrop_SelectedIndexChanged=
{

    $DepCodeChoice = $DepCodeDrop.SelectedItem.ToString()
    $DepCodeChoice
    Write-Host $DepCodeChoice
    [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("STARTING SCRIPTBLOCK")

    #Start-Job -ScriptBlock { CheckValues } -Args InitializationScript $CheckValues
    Start-Job -ScriptBlock $CheckValues

}
    $MSOffVerDrop_SelectedIndexChanged=
{

    $MSOffVerChoice = $MSOffVerDrop.SelectedItem.ToString()
    $MSOffVerChoice
    #$MSOffVerChoice = $True
    Write-Host $MSOffVerChoice

    }
    $PartitionDrop_SelectedIndexChanged=
    {

    $PartitionChoice = $PartitionDrop.SelectedItem.ToString()
    $PartitionChoice
    #$PartitionChoice = $True
    Write-Host $PartitionChoice
    }
    $AcroDrop_SelectedIndexChanged=
{


    $AcroChoice = $AcroDrop.SelectedItem.ToString()
    $AcroChoice
    #$AcroChoice = $True
    Write-Host $AcroChoice

}
    $BuildTechDrop_SelectedIndexChanged=
{
    $BuildTechChoice = $BuildTechDrop.SelectedItem.ToString()
    $BuildTechChoice
    #$BuildTechChoice = $True
    Write-Host $BuildTechChoice
}

    $DepCodeDrop.add_SelectedIndexChanged($DepCodeDrop_SelectedIndexChanged)
    $MSOffVerDrop.add_SelectedIndexChanged($MSOffVerDrop_SelectedIndexChanged)
    $PartitionDrop.add_SelectedIndexChanged($PartitionDrop_SelectedIndexChanged)
    $AcroDrop.add_SelectedIndexChanged($AcroDrop_SelectedIndexChanged)
    $BuildTechDrop.add_SelectedIndexChanged($BuildTechDrop_SelectedIndexChanged)





$CheckValues = {
        function CheckValues
    {
        [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
        [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("RUNNING SCRIPTBLOCK")
        $button.Visible = $true
        $RequiredValues = @($BuildTechChoice, $AcroChoice, $MSOffVerChoice, $DepCodeChoice, $PartitionChoice)
        Write-Host $RequiredValues

        while ($RequiredValues -lt 4) { }

        $Form.controls.add($button)
        $Form.height = 500
        $Form.Width = 695

    }


}

$button.add_click({ $Form.Close()
})

[void]$Form.showdialog()
```

I want that button to show once the scriptblock sees 5 values in the array.

I am still testing is the while loop will work and will scriptblock even be able to see the array?

Even if i add the add button BEFORE the loop i don't get the button on the form?

How can i use scriptblock to add the button to the main form? What do i need to pass into scriptblock for this to happen?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not great with forms, but I'm pretty sure you need to add the button beforehand, and set the button's .Visible = $false, then have you script change that to $true

Comment: Just trying that and I can add the button - but the $button.visible = $true inside the scriptblock wont make the button visible so i think its the same issue - the scriptblock cannot amend the form? If i run the loop in the main form script the form hangs and cannot be amended - hence the scriptblock. Not as simple as i first thought!

Comment: Ah, no, it can't. You'll want the function to return something when called that the form can see and make the button visible if needed.

Comment: I know you only supplied partial code, but can you show all of it (either here or someplace else) so we can look at it and find a good solution?

Comment: Its lengthy but yeah I will give it a try Thanks

Comment: I see the issue now. You cannot add a control from a background job. The variable cannot be accessed across process (PSJobs spin up  a new process to run), only across threads when using a runspace and synchronized collection. You will need to add the button on the Event of the control.

Comment: How would i add a loop to check the array within the form - so that it does not hang the form? will post the code momentarily

Comment: How can i start a new thread and not process? I have something i did in VB.net that starts new threads but powershell i keep finding references to scriptblock which is no use?

Comment: I wrote this a while back and talks about using WPF instead of WinForms, but shows how to use runspaces with UIs to share variables and update the UI on another thread. [http://learn-powershell.net/2012/10/14/powershell-and-wpf-writing-data-to-a-ui-from-a-different-runspace/](http://learn-powershell.net/2012/10/14/powershell-and-wpf-writing-data-to-a-ui-from-a-different-runspace/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I ripped out all of the background job stuff and made sure that the button was added (but not made visible) in the form prior to calling the form to open. What I did was create a timer event which will track each selection change (each choice = $True) and then when all are true, it will display the button. The timer is on a 1 second tick (1000ms) so there could be a slight delay in the button displaying. I also got rid of the annoying numbers that would come up each time you added an item to the combobox.

Here is the code in its entirety:

```
$BuildTech = "x:\Scripts\PowerShell\BuildTech.txt"
$Acrobat = "x:\Scripts\PowerShell\Acrobat.txt"
$Partition = "x:\Scripts\Powershell\Drives.txt"
$MSOffver = "x:\Scripts\Powershell\OfficeVer.txt"
$DepCode = "x:\Scripts\Powershell\DepCodes.txt"

$CompName = $Null

[array]$BuildTechDropArray = Get-Content $BuildTech
[array]$AcroDropArray = Get-Content $Acrobat
[array]$PartitionDropArray = Get-Content $Partition
[array]$MSOffVerDropArray = Get-Content $MSOffver
[array]$DepCodeDropArray = Get-Content $DepCode

[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing")
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")

[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles();

$Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form

$Radio1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton
$Radio2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton
$Radio3 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton
$Radio4 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton
$Radio5 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton
$Radio6 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton

$Radio1.Checked = $True

Function Get-OptimalSize()
{
    Param ([int64]$sizeInBytes)
    switch ($sizeInBytes)
    {
        { $sizeInBytes -ge 1TB } { "{0:n$sigDigits}" -f ($sizeInBytes/1TB) + " TB"; break }
        { $sizeInBytes -ge 1GB } { "{0:n$sigDigits}" -f ($sizeInBytes/1GB) + " GB"; break }
        { $sizeInBytes -ge 1MB } { "{0:n$sigDigits}" -f ($sizeInBytes/1MB) + " MB"; break }
        { $sizeInBytes -ge 1KB } { "{0:n$sigDigits}" -f ($sizeInBytes/1KB) + " KB"; break }
        Default { "{0:n$sigDigits}" -f $sizeInBytes + " Bytes" }
    }
}

$diskdrive = gwmi win32_diskdrive
$a =
foreach ($drive in $diskdrive)
{

    $InterFaceType = "$($Drive.InterfaceType)"
    If (!($InterFaceType -eq "USB"))
    {
        $Size = "$($drive.size)"
        $DriveModel = "`nDrive: $($drive.deviceid.substring(4))  Model: $($drive.model)"
        $Size = Get-OptimalSize $Size
        $DriveModel + "     " + $Size
        [Array]$a = $a + $Result
    }
}

$a = $a | Sort-Object

$Drive1 = $a[0] 
$Drive2 = $a[1]
$Drive3 = $a[2]
$Drive4 = $a[3]
$Drive5 = $a[4]
$Drive6 = $a[5]

If (-not ($Drive1 -eq $null)) { $Drive1 = $Drive1.trim() }
If (-not ($Drive2 -eq $null)) { $Drive2 = $Drive2.trim() }
If (-not ($Drive3 -eq $null)) { $Drive3 = $Drive3.trim() }
If (-not ($Drive3 -eq $null)) { $Drive4 = $Drive4.trim() }
If (-not ($Drive3 -eq $null)) { $Drive5 = $Drive5.trim() }
If (-not ($Drive3 -eq $null)) { $Drive6 = $Drive6.trim() }

If($a[0]){
    $DiskID1 = $a[0].SubString(21,1)
    $Radio1.BackColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::’Transparent’
    $System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
    $System_Drawing_Size.Width = 500
    $System_Drawing_Size.Height = 15    
    $Radio1.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
    $Radio1.TabIndex = 8
    $Radio1.Text = $Drive1
    $System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
    $System_Drawing_Point.X = 15
    $System_Drawing_Point.Y = 255
    $Radio1.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
    $Radio1.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
    $Radio1.Name = "Radio1"
    $Form.Controls.Add($Radio1)

}
If($a[1]){
    $DiskID2 = $a[1].SubString(21,1)
    $Radio2.BackColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::’Transparent’
    $System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
    $System_Drawing_Size.Width = 500
    $System_Drawing_Size.Height = 15
    $Radio2.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
    $Radio2.TabIndex = 9
    $Radio2.Text = $Drive2
    $System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
    $System_Drawing_Point.X = 15
    $System_Drawing_Point.Y = 275
    $Radio2.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
    $Radio2.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
    $Radio2.Name = "Radio2"
    $Form.Controls.Add($Radio2)
}
If($a[2]){
    $DiskID3 = $a[2].SubString(21,1)
    $Radio3.BackColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::’Transparent’
    $System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
    $System_Drawing_Size.Width = 500
    $System_Drawing_Size.Height = 15
    $Radio3.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
    $Radio3.TabIndex = 10
    $Radio3.Text = $Drive3
    $System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
    $System_Drawing_Point.X = 15
    $System_Drawing_Point.Y = 295
    $Radio3.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
    $Radio3.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
    $Radio3.Name = "Radio3"
    $Form.Controls.Add($Radio3)
}
If($a[3]){
    $DiskID4 = $a[3].SubString(21,1)
    $Radio4.BackColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::’Transparent’
    $System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
    $System_Drawing_Size.Width = 500
    $System_Drawing_Size.Height = 15
    $Radio4.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
    $Radio4.TabIndex = 11
    $Radio4.Text = $Drive4
    $System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
    $System_Drawing_Point.X = 15
    $System_Drawing_Point.Y = 315
    $Radio4.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
    $Radio4.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
    $Radio4.Name = "Radio4"
    $Form.Controls.Add($Radio4)
}
If($a[4]){  
    $DiskID5 = $a[4].SubString(21,1)
    $Radio5.BackColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::’Transparent’
    $System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
    $System_Drawing_Size.Width = 500
    $System_Drawing_Size.Height = 15
    $Radio5.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
    $Radio5.TabIndex = 12
    $Radio5.Text = $Drive5
    $System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
    $System_Drawing_Point.X = 15
    $System_Drawing_Point.Y = 335
    $Radio5.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
    $Radio5.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
    $Radio5.Name = "Radio5"
    $Form.Controls.Add($Radio5)
}
If($a[5]){
    $DiskID6 = $a[5].SubString(21,1)
    $Radio6.BackColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::’Transparent’
    $System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
    $System_Drawing_Size.Width = 500
    $System_Drawing_Size.Height = 15
    $Radio6.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
    $Radio6.TabIndex = 13
    $Radio6.Text = $Drive6
    $System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
    $System_Drawing_Point.X = 15
    $System_Drawing_Point.Y = 355
    $Radio6.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
    $Radio6.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
    $Radio6.Name = "Radio6"
    $Form.Controls.Add($Radio6)
}

    $Radio7 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton
    $Radio7.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(8,8)
    $Radio7.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(140,27)
    $Radio7.BackColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::’Transparent’
    $Radio7.Checked = $True
    $Radio7.Text = "WINDOWS 7"
    $Radio7.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
    $Radio7.Name = "Radio7"
    #$Radio7.TabIndex = 6
    #$groupbox1.Controls.Add($Radio7)

    $Radio8 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton
    $Radio8.BackColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::’Transparent’
    $Radio8.ForeColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::'Red'
    $Radio8.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(8,28)
    $Radio8.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(170,27)

    #$Radio8.TabIndex = 10
    $Radio8.Text = "WINDOWS 7 UPGRADE"

    $Radio8.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
$Radio8.Name = "Radio8"
#$Radio8.TabIndex = 7
    #$groupbox1.Controls.Add($Radio8)


$InitialFormWindowState = $Form.WindowState
$Form.add_Load($OnLoadForm_StateCorrection)

$LANDESK = [system.drawing.image]::FromFile("x:\Scripts\Powershell\logo-lg.gif")
$PS = [system.drawing.image]::FromFile("x:\Scripts\Powershell\PS2.png")
$PictureBox = New-Object Windows.Forms.PictureBox
$PictureBox.Image = $LANDESK
$PictureBox.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(12, 372)
$PictureBox.Width = $LANDESK.Size.Width
$PictureBox.Height = $LANDESK.Size.Height
$Form.Controls.Add($PictureBox)

$PictureBox2 = New-Object Windows.Forms.PictureBox
$PictureBox2.Image = $PS
$PictureBox2.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(588, 365)
$Form.Controls.Add($PictureBox2)

$Form.BackColor = 'White'
$Form.width = 695
$Form.height = 500

$Form.Text = "PowerShell Provisioning Tool                                                                                                                                 Gary Stewart 2014"
$Form.MinimizeBox = $False
$Form.MaximizeBox = $False
$Form.ControlBox = $False
$Form.topmost = $true

$MainLabel = new-object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$MainLabel.BackColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::’Transparent’
$MainLabel.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(10,5)
$MainLabel.size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(500,20)
$MainLabel.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font(“Tahoma Bold”, 14.25, 0, 3, 0)
$MainLabel.ForeColor = 'DimGray'
$MainLabel.Text = "PLEASE CUSTOMISE YOUR WINDOWS INSTALL"
$Form.Controls.Add($MainLabel)

$MainLabelWarning = new-object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$MainLabelWarning.BackColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::’Transparent’
$MainLabelWarning.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(10,352)
$MainLabelWarning.size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(450,20)
$MainLabelWarning.ForeColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::'Red'
$MainLabelWarning.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font(“Tahoma”,9.25, 0,3,0)
$MainLabelWarning.Text = "PLEASE ENSURE ALL OPTIONS ARE SELECTED BEFORE CLICKING SUBMIT"
$Form.Controls.Add($MainLabelWarning)

$BuildTechDrop = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
$BuildTechDrop.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(110,45)
$BuildTechDrop.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(198,21)
$BuildTechDrop.DropDownStyle = [System.Windows.Forms.ComboBoxStyle]::DropDownList;
$BuildTechDrop.tabIndex = 0
$Form.Controls.Add($BuildTechDrop)

$BuildTechDropLabel = new-object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$BuildTechDropLabel.BackColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::’Transparent’
$BuildTechDropLabel.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(12,47)
$BuildTechDropLabel.size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(90,20)
$BuildTechDropLabel.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font(“Tahoma Bold”,9.75, 0,3,0)
$BuildTechDropLabel.Text = "Build Tech"
$Form.Controls.Add($BuildTechDropLabel)

$AcroDrop = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
$AcroDrop.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(110,75)
$AcroDrop.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(198,21)
$AcroDrop.DropDownStyle = [System.Windows.Forms.ComboBoxStyle]::DropDownList;
$AcroDrop.tabIndex = 1
$Form.Controls.Add($AcroDrop)

$AcroDropLabel = new-object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$AcroDropLabel.BackColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::’Transparent’
$AcroDropLabel.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(12,75)
$AcroDropLabel.size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(95,20)
$AcroDropLabel.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font(“Tahoma Bold”,9.75, 0,3,0)
$AcroDropLabel.Text = "Adobe Acrobat"
$Form.Controls.Add($AcroDropLabel)

$PartitionDrop = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
$PartitionDrop.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(495,45)
$PartitionDrop.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(166,21)
$PartitionDrop.DropDownStyle = [System.Windows.Forms.ComboBoxStyle]::DropDownList;
$PartitionDrop.tabIndex = 2
$Form.Controls.Add($PartitionDrop)

$PartitionDropLabel = new-object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$PartitionDropLabel.BackColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::’Transparent’
$PartitionDropLabel.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(375,47)
$PartitionDropLabel.size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(90,20)
$PartitionDropLabel.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font(“Tahoma Bold”,9.75, 0,3,0)
$PartitionDropLabel.Text = "Partitioning"
$Form.Controls.Add($PartitionDropLabel)

$MSOffVerDrop = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
$MSOffVerDrop.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(495,75)
$MSOffVerDrop.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(166,21)
$MSOffVerDrop.DropDownStyle = [System.Windows.Forms.ComboBoxStyle]::DropDownList;
$MSOffVerDrop.tabIndex = 3
$Form.Controls.Add($MSOffVerDrop)

$MSOffVerDropLabel = new-object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$MSOffVerDropLabel.BackColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::’Transparent’
$MSOffVerDropLabel.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(375,75)
$MSOffVerDropLabel.size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(120,20)
$MSOffVerDropLabel.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font(“Tahoma Bold”,9.75, 0,3,0)
$MSOffVerDropLabel.Text = "MS Office Version"
$Form.Controls.Add($MSOffVerDropLabel)

$DepCodeDrop = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
$DepCodeDrop.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(110,105)
$DepCodeDrop.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(551,21)
$DepCodeDrop.DropDownStyle = [System.Windows.Forms.ComboBoxStyle]::DropDownList;
$DepCodeDrop.tabIndex = 4
$Form.Controls.Add($DepCodeDrop)

$DepCodeDropLabel = new-object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$DepCodeDropLabel.BackColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::’Transparent’
$DepCodeDropLabel.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(12,107)
$DepCodeDropLabel.size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(80,20)
$DepCodeDropLabel.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font(“Tahoma Bold”,9.75, 0,3,0)
$DepCodeDropLabel.Text = "Dep Code"
$Form.Controls.Add($DepCodeDropLabel)

$BarcodeInputLabel = new-object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$BarcodeInputLabel.BackColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::’Transparent’
$BarcodeInputLabel.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(12,135)
$BarcodeInputLabel.size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(95,21)
$BarcodeInputLabel.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font(“Tahoma Bold”,9.75, 0,3,0)
$BarcodeInputLabel.Text = "Insert Barcode"
$Form.Controls.Add($BarcodeInputLabel)

$BarcodeInput = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox 
$BarcodeInput.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(110,135) 
$BarcodeInput.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(198,21) 
$BarcodeInput.tabIndex = 5
$Form.Controls.Add($BarcodeInput)

$UpgradeOSCheck = new-object System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
$UpgradeOSCheck.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(15,160)
$UpgradeOSCheck.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(286, 24)
$UpgradeOSCheck.Text = "     WINDOWS 7 UPGRADE"
$UpgradeOSCheck.tabIndex = 6
$Form.Controls.Add($UpgradeOSCheck)

$App1Box = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
$App1Box.BackColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::’Transparent’
$App1Box.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(15,180)
$App1Box.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(250,24)
$App1Box.Text = "     INSTALL CISCO ANYCONNECT CLIENT"
$App1Box.TabIndex = 7
$Form.Controls.Add($App1Box)

$App2Box = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
$App2Box.BackColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::’Transparent’
$App2Box.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(15,200)
$App2Box.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(250,24)
$App2Box.Text = "     INSTALL AVAMAR CLIENT"
$App2Box.TabIndex = 7
$Form.Controls.Add($App2Box)

$FormatLabel = new-object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$FormatLabel.BackColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::’Transparent’
$FormatLabel.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(12,230)
$FormatLabel.size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(340,20)
$FormatLabel.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font(“Tahoma Bold”, 10.75, 0, 3, 0)
$FormatLabel.ForeColor = 'DimGray'
$FormatLabel.Text = "PLEASE SELECT DISK TO INSTALL OS ONTO"
$Form.Controls.Add($FormatLabel)

$WarningLabel = new-object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$WarningLabel.BackColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::’Transparent’
$WarningLabel.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(10,410)
$WarningLabel.size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(450,10)
$WarningLabel.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font(“Tahoma Bold”, 7, 0, 3, 0)
$WarningLabel.ForeColor = 'SteelBlue'
$WarningLabel.Text = "This tool is provided as is. It is not affiliated with LANDESK in any way. Thank you! "
$Form.Controls.Add($WarningLabel)


ForEach ($Item in $DepCodeDropArray) {
    [void]$DepCodeDrop.Items.Add($Item)
}

ForEach ($Item in $MSOffVerDropArray) {
    [void]$MSOffVerDrop.Items.Add($Item)
}

ForEach ($Item in $PartitionDropArray) {
    [void]$PartitionDrop.Items.Add($Item)
}
ForEach ($Item in $AcroDropArray) {
    [void]$AcroDrop.Items.Add($Item)
}
ForEach ($Item in $BuildTechDropArray) {
    [void]$BuildTechDrop.Items.Add($Item)
}

$Script:button = New-Object Windows.Forms.Button
$button.text = "SUBMIT"
$button.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(12, 423)
$button.size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(245, 37)
$button.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font(“Tahoma Bold”, 12.75, 0, 3, 0)
$button.BackColor = 'SteelBlue'
$button.ForeColor = "White"
$button.tabIndex = 14
$button.Visible = $False
$Form.controls.add($button)



    $DepCodeDrop_SelectedIndexChanged=
{
    $Script:DepCodeChoice = $True
    Write-Host $DepCodeChoice
}
    $MSOffVerDrop_SelectedIndexChanged=
{

    $Script:MSOffVerChoice = $True
    Write-Host $MSOffVerChoice

    }
    $PartitionDrop_SelectedIndexChanged=
    {

    $Script:PartitionChoice = $True
    Write-Host $PartitionChoice
    }
    $AcroDrop_SelectedIndexChanged=
{
    $Script:AcroChoice = $True
    Write-Host $AcroChoice

}
    $BuildTechDrop_SelectedIndexChanged=
{
    $Script:BuildTechChoice = $True
    Write-Host $BuildTechChoice
}

    $DepCodeDrop.add_SelectedIndexChanged($DepCodeDrop_SelectedIndexChanged)
    $MSOffVerDrop.add_SelectedIndexChanged($MSOffVerDrop_SelectedIndexChanged)
    $PartitionDrop.add_SelectedIndexChanged($PartitionDrop_SelectedIndexChanged)
    $AcroDrop.add_SelectedIndexChanged($AcroDrop_SelectedIndexChanged)
    $BuildTechDrop.add_SelectedIndexChanged($BuildTechDrop_SelectedIndexChanged)

#Create a timer to watch for all selections to be true
$timer = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Timer $objForm
$timer.Interval = 1000  # once per second
$timer.Add_Tick({
    If ($Script:AcroChoice -AND $Script:DepCodeChoice -AND $Script:PartitionChoice -AND $Script:BuildTechChoice -AND $Script:MSOffVerChoice) {
        $Script:button.Visible=$True
    }
})
$timer.Start()


$button.add_click({ 
    $Form.Close()
    $timer.Stop()
    $timer.Dispose()
    Remove-Variable AcroChoice,DepCodeChoice,PartitionChoice,BuildTechChoice,MSOffVerChoice,button -Scope Script
})
[void]$Form.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: That works like a dream... Thank you so much! And for the quick response.